# Question on Converse of Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have an implicit function $F(x,y)=0$. Suppose we know that there exists open sets $V,W$ and a differentiable explicit function $f:V \to W$ with $y=f(x)$ and $F(x,f(x))=0$ for $x \in V$. Furthermore, we know that $f'(x)>0 \text{ } \forall x \in V$ and $F_y(x,y)$ exists.

Can we show that $F_x(x,y)$ exists on $V \times W$? Can we show that $F_x(x,y)$ is non-singular on $V \times W$? I'm guessing the answer is no, but I figured it was worth a shot.

As a side note, it's reasonably simple to find a case where $F_x(x,y)$ does not exist if we relax the condition that $F_y(x,y)$ exists: Take $F(x,y)=(x-y)^{1/3}$. Then, we have that $f(x)=x$ satisfies this equation, but $F_x(x,f(x))$ doesn't exist anywhere - however, neither does $F_y(x,f(x))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality let's take $U=W = (0,1).$ If I understand correctly, the question is equivalent to the following: we are given that  $F$ has a $C^1$ and increasing $0$-level curve and that $F_y$ exists in $(0,1)\times (0,1).$ Does it follow that $F_x$ exists everywhere on $(0,1)^2.$ The answer is no. $F$ doesn't have to be even continuous. As $f$, take for example, $f(x)=x.$ Define $F$ as follows:  $F(x,y) = 0$ for $y\ge x$ and $F(x,y) = 0$ for $x < 1/2$. Set $F(x,0) = 1$ for $x> 1/2$ and on each line segment connecting $(x,0)$ to $(x,x)$ $x > 1/2$ define $F$ to smoothly decrease to $0$ so that $F_y(x,x) = 0.$ Thus we get $F$ satisfying all of the conditions described in the question and discontinuous along the line segment $(1/2,0)$ -$(1/2,1/2).$

Comment: Thanks, that works for me.